# Active profile ignored by maven-release-plugin in multi-module build

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a multi-module maven build that requires a profile to be activated only on demand using the -P flag. But for some reason it is being ignored when doing a release using the maven-release-plugin.

The following command line activates the profile correctly and disables the activeByDefault profile:

```
mvn clean deploy -Poracle
```

But when doing a release with the following command:

```
mvn help:active-profiles release:clean release:prepare release:perform -Poracle
```

...the profile is reported as being active by the active-profiles output but in fact only the activeByDefault profile is enabled.

Is this the expected behaviour or am I missing some maven magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved. Profiles must be specified as a configuration parameter to the [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#releaseProfiles).